# Jest unite test case `No instances found with testID: callHistoryList`

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, ts-jest, testcase

I'm using the jest library for testing but I got the error  `No instances found with testID: callHistoryList`

I tried with queryByTestId then it work but with queryByTestId methods are not work like onEndReached and onRefresh

My Code

```
        {!this.state.loadSuccess ? (
          <Text testID="loading" style={styles.emptyText}>
            {this.state.loadState}
          </Text>
        ) : (
            <SearchBar
              testID="search"
              icon="md-search"
              placeholder={Search}
              keyboardType="numeric"
              onChange={text => this.onChangeSearchText(text)}
            />

          <RecyclerListView
           testID="callHistoryList"
           dataProvider={this.state.callHistory}
           renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
           layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
           extendedState={{
            progressIndex: this.state.progressIndex,
            playingIndex: this.state.playingIndex,
           }}
           rowRenderer={(type, item, index) =>
            this.renderHistoryRow(item, index)
           }
            scrollEventThrottle: 400,
        />
      )}
```

Test case

```
  test('Call history should be visble', async () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(response));
    let rendered = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HistoryView navigation={navigation} />
      </Provider>,
    );

    let header = rendered.getByTestId('header').props;
    expect(header.children).toBe('Prank History');

    expect(rendered.getByTestId('loading')).toBeVisible;

    let content = rendered.getByTestId('callHistoryList');
    expect(content).toBe(null);

    const {refreshControl, onEndReached} = content.props;
    refreshControl.props.onRefresh();
    onEndReached();
    onEndReached();

  });
```

Any one know how to fix this error